# Counting working days in SAS EG

Tags: sas

Hi to all and good time of a day!
Here is my case I need to solve I will very gratefull if you can help me.
I have some data set it contains only one variable date format.
Example:

```
01JAN2016
06JAN2016
15FEB2016
```

The second data set is days - holidays for a period 5 years.
Example:

```
01JAN2016
02JAN2016
```

and etc, all these days are not working days.

The case is I need to count number of working days from date for every observation from first data set till now. It seems that I need to count number of days

**"Now date"  minus Date(from first data set) and minus number of days from second data set with holidays (count(date) where Date(from first data set)< date < "Now"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own type of interval to use with SAS funcions intck and intnx. Here's how to do it:

First create a table of weekdays for whichever years you have holidays for, up to present (or a future) year.

Here we'll start by including all weekdays from 2014 to 2016. This is assuming you don't want to count weekend days. If that's not the case, just modify the code so that the condition "weekday(date) in (2:6)" is not applied. You'll get the full 365 days of the year.

```
data mon_fri;
  do date = "01JAN2014"d to "31DEC2016"d;
     if weekday(date) in (2:6) then output;
  end;
  format date date9.;
run;
```

Then we'll create a table having all those dates we just created, minus the holidays we have in the table Holidays. We'll place the table in a library called myLib, and rename the date column to "Begin" for compliance with SAS custom intervals.

```
libname myLib "some/place/on/your/drive";

data mylib.workdays(RENAME=(date=Begin));
  merge mon_fri (in=weekday)
        Holidays (in=holiday);
  by date;
  if weekday and not holiday then output;
run;
```

Now we set up a custom interval which we'll simply call "workdays".

```
options intervalds=(workdays=mylib.workdays);
```

From there, all you have left to do is something like this:

```
data dateCalculations;
  set mydata;
  numOfDays = intck("workdays", theDate, today());
run;
```

SAS will take care of counting the number of dates (lines in the workdays dataset) separating the startdate (column called theDate) from the enddate (today's date).

Et voilà!

Comment: Thank you, but I need to count Holidays+Weekends

Comment: Ok well then just put in every date you need to count in a dataset as I did and define your custom interval using that dataset! You can get weekends with `weekday(date) in (1,7)`, and then concatenate those with your holidays, sort by date, rename column to "Begin" and you're ready to go!

Answer (score 0):

This is wonderful and very helpful. I use two different SAS systems (both on remote Unix servers). Setting the intervalds option only seems to work on one of them. I copy/paste the same code and on the other nothing happens - no warning, no error, it simply doesn't work.

Here is how I'm setting it (download the CSV from Yahoo! Finance for the S&P500, daily data, starting January 1950):

```
PROC IMPORT DATAFILE="sp500_1950_2016.csv"
            OUT=sp500_1950_2016
            DBMS=DLM
            REPLACE;
            delimiter=',';
            getnames=yes;
RUN;
data trading_days; 
set sp500_1950_2016 (keep = date rename=(date=begin));
    where year(begin) < 2017;
run;
options intervalds=(TradingDay=trading_days) ;
```

Then I call it like so to count number of observations I should have from fund inception to Dec 31, 2016 or when the fund closed, whichever is sooner:

```
data ops2; set operations_master; where ~missing(inception);
if missing(enddate) then enddate = '31dec2016'd;
datadays = INTCK('TradingDay',inception,enddate);run;
proc univariate; var datadays;run;quit;
```

On system 1, this works just fine. On system 2, I get 0 for the variable datadays. I've already checked to see if there is a sys admin override on setting the intervalds option, and there is not. Is there another reason why this might not work on a given system?